# Extracting an element from a queue and then printing the elements - doesn't work at the last element

Tags: c, insert, queue, extract

I am trying to insert into the queue 3 elements , then extract each one of them . After each extraction , I am printing the remaining elements . The problem is that at the last element , it shows me that I have extracted the right element , but that element still remains in the queue .

The output is like this : 
Print : 8 1 4

Extracted : 4
Print : 8 1

Extracted : 1
Print : 8

Extracted : 8
Print : 8 ----> here is the problem . It should be : "No elements !"

```
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct Nod{
    int id;
    Nod* next;
};

Nod* insert(Nod* nod,int id){
    Nod* nou = (Nod*)malloc(sizeof(Nod));
    nou->id = id;
    nou->next = 0;

    if (nod == 0)
        nod = nou;
    else
    {
        nou->next = nod;
        nod = nou;
    }

    return nod;
}

int extract(Nod* nod){
    if (nod->next == 0){
        Nod* temp = nod;
        nod = 0;
        return temp->id;
    }
    else
    {
        Nod* temp = nod;
        while (temp->next->next)
            temp = temp->next;
        Nod* aux = temp->next;
        temp->next = 0;
        return aux->id;
    }
}

void print(Nod* nod){
    if (nod == 0)
        printf("\nNo elements !\n");
    else
    {
        printf("\nPrint : ");
        Nod* temp = nod;
        while (temp){
            printf("%d ",temp->id);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main(){
    Nod* nod = 0;

    ///////////
    nod = insert(nod, 4);
    nod = insert(nod, 1);
    nod = insert(nod, 8);

    print(nod);

    ///////////
    int r = extract(nod);
    printf("\nExtracted : %d",r);
    print(nod);
    ///
    int y = extract(nod);
    printf("\nExtracted : %d", y);
    print(nod);
    ///
    int p = extract(nod);
    printf("\nExtracted : %d", p);
    print(nod);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int extract(Nod* nod){
if (nod->next == 0){
    Nod* temp = nod;
    nod = 0;
    return temp->id;
}
```

The problem lies in the above code.When there is only one element left you are  making `nod` `0` but it is not getting reflected as `nod` is passed by value.You can pass `nod` as reference.

```
int extract(Nod* &nod){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int extract(Nod* *nod){
    if (((*nod)->next) == 0){
        Nod* temp = *nod;
        *nod = 0;
        return temp->id;
    }
    else
    {
        Nod* temp = *nod;
        while (temp->next->next)
            temp = temp->next;
        Nod* aux = temp->next;
        temp->next = 0;
        return aux->id;
    }
}
```

This is how I wrote the code and it works ! :) Thank you !